# Replacing NA values with column means

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 12 columns that have NA values,
I can replace the NA values with the mean of the columns if I do:

```
data$F1[which(is.na(data$F1))] <- mean(data$F1,na.rm = TRUE)
```

And continue separately for each column.

How can I code a for loop that will check each column and replace NA with mean value:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)}
```

I get the error: object not found.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns, `replace` the `NA` elements based on the index with `mean` of that value

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

Or it is easier with `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which by default uses `FUN = mean`

> na.aggregate(object, by = 1, ..., FUN = mean,
>                na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = Inf)

```
library(zoo)
data1 <- na.aggregate(data)
```

---

If we are using a `for` loop, would recommend to subset the column with `[[` instead of `[` as the 'data' could be `data.frame` or `tbl_df` or `data.table` and all of them works with `[[` in extracting the column

```
for(i in seq_along(data)) data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- 
          mean(data[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, if i wanted to replace the NAs with the column group's mean i get the following error? 
> data<-data%>%
+   group_by("ID")%>%
+     lapply( function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
Error: Column `"ID"` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable. 
What can i do?

Comment: @Juan Try. `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_all(~ replace_na(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks. With "~" i refer to all columns?
the following error is returned:
`mutate_all()` ignored the following grouping variables:
Column `ID`
Use `mutate_at(df, vars(-group_cols()), myoperation)` to silence the message.

Comment: @Juan It is anonymous function compact form, i.e. `function(x) x` instead here it is `~ .` for each. column value

Comment: meaning i could use ~ instead of writing function(x). Is this applicable for dyplyr only or with any package? Thanks

Comment: @Juan If you are using it outside tidyverse, you can wrap it with `as_mapper` i.e. `f1  <- as_mapper(~ . + 5);
 f1(6)
[1] 11`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know how to replace all the NA values with column means is using the tidyr package's replace_na function. The two arguments you need are the dataframe and a list of values to replace na's with (first value in the list is what NA's in the first column are replaced with, second value is what NA's in the second column are replaced with, and so on...).

You can use lapply to get the column means:

```
col_means <- lapply(data, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
data1 <- replace_na(data, col_means)
```

Answer (score 0):

First comment was close to right, or atleast it didn't work with my code. Here is my example how it works:

data666 <- apply(data, 2, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))

This function replace NA values counting mean values column wise.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers will work, but if you want to replace your NA values with group means and not just column means, I have found a solution using dplyr's mutate_at function

```
    library(dplyr)
    data(airquality, package = 'datasets')
    str(airquality)

         Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
    1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
    2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2   
    3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
    4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
    5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
    6      28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
    7      23     299  8.6   65     5   7

    airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% mutate_at(vars(Ozone), ~ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .))
```

This will replace NA values in the Ozone column with means by month, not the entire column

```
    Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
  1  41       190   7.4    67     5     1
  2  36       118   8      72     5     2
  3  12       149  12.6    74     5     3
  4  18       313  11.5    62     5     4
  5  23.6      NA  14.3    56     5     5
  6  28        NA  14.9    66     5     6
  7  23       299   8.6    65     5     7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  num = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  aa = c(1, NA, NA, 2, 3, 4),
  bb = c(NA, NA, 2, 4, 5, 6),
  cc = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2)
)
df
# > df
# num aa bb cc
# 1   1  1 NA  6
# 2   2 NA NA  7
# 3   3 NA  2  8
# 4   4  2  4  9
# 5   5  3  5  1
# 6   6  4  6  2

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(across(aa:cc, ~coalesce(.x, mean(get(cur_column()), na.rm = TRUE))))
df_new
# > df_new
# num  aa   bb cc
# 1   1 1.0 4.25  6
# 2   2 2.5 4.25  7
# 3   3 2.5 2.00  8
# 4   4 2.0 4.00  9
# 5   5 3.0 5.00  1
# 6   6 4.0 6.00  2
```